# How to set the value of a Pyspark column based on two conditions of the value of another column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|id   |foo. |bar. |
+-----+-----+-----+
|    1|  baz|    0|
|    2|  baz|    0|
|    3|  333|    2|
|    4|  444|    1|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

I want to set the 'foo' column to a value depending on the value of bar.

If bar is 2: set the value of foo for that row to 'X',

else if bar is 1: set the value of foo for that row to 'Y'

And if neither condition is met, leave the foo value as it is.

[pyspark.when](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.when) seems like the closest method, but that doesn't seem to work based on another columns value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`when` can work with other columns. You can use `F.col` to get the value of the other column and provide an appropriate condition:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'foo', 
    F.when(F.col('bar') == 2, 'X')
     .when(F.col('bar') == 1, 'Y')
     .otherwise(F.col('foo'))
)

df2.show()
+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
|  1|baz|  0|
|  2|baz|  0|
|  3|  X|  2|
|  4|  Y|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this using `when` òr `UDF` in spark to insert new column based on condition.

Create Sample DataFrame:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('AddConditionalColumn').getOrCreate()

data = [(1,"baz",0),(2,"baz",0),(3,"333",2),(4,"444",1)]

columns = ["id","foo","bar"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = data, schema = columns)
df.show()

+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
|  1|baz|  0|
|  2|baz|  0|
|  3|333|  2|
|  4|444|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Using When:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df2 = df.withColumn("foo", when(df.bar == 2,"X")
                           .when(df.bar == 1,"Y")
                           .otherwise(df.foo))
df2.show()

+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
|  1|baz|  0|
|  2|baz|  0|
|  3|  X|  2|
|  4|  Y|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

Using UDF:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def executeRule(value):
    if value == 2:
        return 'X'
    elif value == 1:
        return 'Y'
    else:
        return value
    
# Converting function to UDF
ruleUDF = F.udf(executeRule, StringType())
df3 = df.withColumn("foo", ruleUDF("bar"))
df3.show()

+---+---+---+
| id|foo|bar|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  0|  0|
|  2|  0|  0|
|  3|  X|  2|
|  4|  Y|  1|
+---+---+---+
```